# How to use C++ lib from python

Tags: python, swig, wordperfect

I would like to know how to use python to make calls to a C++ library called [libwpd](http://libwpd.sourceforge.net/) to read word perfect files and build python objects from them, but I have no experience with C++ or calling C++ functions from python, and I don't understand how to figure out what the output of these library functions would be. So that's really two questions:

- 1) how to call C++ functions from python, and

  2) how to figure out what the output of these functions would be--namely, the result of the **WPDocument::parse** function (*see* http://www.abisource.com/~uwog/libwpd/) and how to use it in my python code. The function appears to return an object **WPDResult**, but I can't figure out what it does or how I would use it.

I looked into SWIG briefly, and it looks promising. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) library allows easy interoperability between C++ and Python.

The [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html) shows how to wrap C++ functions and classes to use them from Python.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html). It's part of the standard Python library set. I can't speak to it's use with C++, but I suspect it will work nicely.

Comment: C++ has no standard binary interface, so ctypes is not guaranteed to work. For calling functions in C binaries it is very nice indeed.